# Displaying data to a grid with ejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

what im trying to do is display news using newsAPI in a grid which is created in for each loop and it randomizes how it looks in each iteration. Problem that i have is obvious, im receiving 3 or 2  but only one instance of data from express each time it loops.Im trying to figure out how to keep grid randomized and receive exact number of data for each div inside the grid.  Since its hard to explain here is the code:

EJS:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <% let current = -1 %>
                    <% data.forEach(function(news){ %>
                        <% let count = Math.floor( Math.random() * Math.floor(4)) %>
                        <% if(count == 0 && count !== current){ %>
                        <div class="row py-2 px-1">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 bg border mainGrid">duh</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md border mainGrid"></div>
                        </div>
                        <% current = count %>
                        <%}else if(count == 1 && count !== current){ %>
                        <div class="row py-2 px-1">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 bg border mainGrid">duh</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md border mainGrid"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 bg border mainGrid">duh</div>
                        </div>
                        <% current = count %>
                        <%}else if(count == 2 && count !== current){ %>
                        <div class="row py-2 px-1">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 bg border mainGrid">duh</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md border mainGrid"></div>
                        </div>
                        <% current = count %>
                        <%}else if(count == 3 && count !== current){ %>
                            <div class="row py-2 px-1">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg border mainGrid">duh</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md border mainGrid"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 bg border mainGrid">duh</div>
                            </div>
                            <% current = count %>
                            <%}%>
                            
                        <% }) %>
```

Express:

```
router.get("/",(req,res) => {
    newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
        sources: 'bbc-news,the-verge',
        language: 'en',
        pageSize: 9
        
      }).then(response => {

        let data = response.articles;
        console.log(data);
        res.render("index",{data:data})
      });
      
})

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If somebody wants to know how i solved it:

```
       <div class="col-md-12">
                    <% let current = 0 %>
                    <% let count = 0 %>
                    <% let currentCount = 0 %>
                    <% data.forEach(function(news){ %>
                      <%    if(current === 1){ %>
                        <%let gridcount = Math.floor((12 - count)/2); %>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-<%=gridcount%> border mainGrid">
                            <h2>
                                <%= news.title %>
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                <%= news.description %>
                            </p>
                    </div>
                
            
                    <% current = 2 %>
                <%  }else if(current == 0){ %>
                    <% while(count == currentCount){ %>
                    <% count = Math.floor( Math.random() * Math.floor(4)) +3 %>
            <%  } %>
                    <div class="row">
                        
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-<%=count%> border mainGrid">
                        <h2>
                                <%= news.title %>
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                <%= news.description %>
                            </p></div>
                    <% currentCount = count %>
                    <% current = 1 %>
                <%  }else if(current == 2){%>
                            
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md border mainGrid">
                        <h2>
                                <%= news.title %>
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                <%= news.description %>
                            </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <% current = 0 %>
                    <%  } %>
                        <% }) %>
                    
                   
                </div>
```